# Error: Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated. when adding a Service reference to Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I have a Xamarin forms v3.1 project with the .NET standard approach.
I tried to add a reference to a web service I have using
"add connected service" and then from the pop up, I choose Microsoft web service reference provider.

I add the web service link, Visual Studio (2017 v15.8) discovers its structure, and then when I click finish, it takes a while but then shows this error:

> Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.  
> You can specify the "-d" option before the tool name for diagnostic 
> output  (for example, "dotnet -d ":  C:\Program 
> Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj
> Done.

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

Comment: is there already a deps.json file somewhere in your folder structure?

Comment: no, there is no deps.json in xamarin forms projects

Comment: Possibly a permissons error: some bugs filed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2128) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8981). Post suggesting that opening up pemissions to directory may [work](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8981#issuecomment-378404548)

Comment: i tried adding permissions for everyone account on the sdk folder but the issue still happens

Answer (score 3):

Execute tool-line command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was running the "dotnet restore" command in VS 2019.

Answer (score 0):

When I add a service reference to a regular.net core web application, I got the same error. After the investigation I came to know that, somehow svcutil was not installed. Once I installed svcutil using Nuget Package Manager (`Install-Package dotnet-svcutil`), this issue resolved.

More details about .net core and svcutil : Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide

Answer (score 0):

For a .NET Core 2 application you cannot install dotnet-scvutil ver 2.0.1. For me it worked with ver 1.0.4.

After you install this you need to update rest of the NuGet packages except dotnet-svcutil.